# data types of all columns of data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas

in my data frame, i have 69 columns. i want to check my all columns data types. i use the following code which gives me the result but it gives only first and last four only.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Muhammad.Tauqeer/Desktop/server column name.csv")
df.dtypes
```

```
ID                                int64
PH_Pin                            int64
Product                          object
Policy_No                         int64
N_R                              object
                                  ...  
Pre-Existing Organ Transplant     int64
Pre-Existing Alzheimer Limit      int64
Pre-Existing Autism Limit         int64
Pre-Existing Disability Limit     int64
Source_File_Name                 object
Length: 69, dtype: object
```

Comment: quick and dirty `for i, z in df.dtypes.items(): print(i,z)`

Comment: ```pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)```